# IOS Swift3 how to Remove Custom UIView randomly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am building an iOS Application in swift 3, where I am creating dynamic UIViews. I need to remove custom view randomly. Please help me I am stuck with this for a long time. **Thanks In Advance**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    var myView: subView! 
    var y : CGFloat! 
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        y = 1
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        y = y + 110
        myView = subView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: y, width: 300, height: 100))

        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        myView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the above image when i click on Close the SubView(custome View) closes, but where as MyView with green color does not go and stays there. Someone please Help.........

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
   {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView",owner: self, options:nil)
       self.addSubview(self.views)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView",owner: self, options:nil)
       self.addSubview(self.views)

   }
   override init(frame: CGRect)
   {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView", owner: self, options: nil)
       views.frame = bounds
       self.addSubview(self.views)
   }

   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       views.removeFromSuperview()

   }
```

Comment: What you have added code in subView  class ?

Comment: You are holding myView = you last view added. Not the view which you want to close / remove.

Comment: required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
   {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView",owner: self, options:nil)
       self.addSubview(self.views)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView",owner: self, options:nil)
       self.addSubview(self.views)
       
   }
   override init(frame: CGRect)
   {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("subView", owner: self, options: nil)
       views.frame = bounds
       self.addSubview(self.views)
   }

Comment: please append code to the question (via edit) and not so much code in comments (because it get unreadable because of missing formatting)

Comment: Hey, just a thought why dont you use tableview instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are doing wrong is that you add multiple views of subView that why you selected does not remove. Please modify your code like given below.
The thing I have done is that whenever you will add new `subView` you will also set its tag value and when you select view to remove its tag value and place an `if` statement on that tag value.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    var myView: subView! 
    var y : CGFloat! 
    var tag : Int = 0 
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        y = 1
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
                let selectViewTagValue : Int = sender.tag /// save the selected view tag value
                for object in self.view.subviews {

                if ((object is subView) && object.tag == selectViewTagValue)
                {
                    object.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
    }
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        y = y + 110
        myView = subView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: y, width: 300, height: 100))
        myView.tag = tag 
        myView.actionButton.tag = tag
        tag = tag + 1
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        myView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

    }
```

Comment: you can add tag directly on `myView.actionButton`

Comment: Yes I added it. Thanks.

Comment: if ((object is subView) && subView.tag == selectViewTagValue)
                {
                    object.removeFromSuperview()
                }

 subView.tag...how can i set Tag here, is this correct?, as im getting error

Comment: please check my code again I have made little silly mistake. and what type of error you are facing now.

Comment: please update you condition like this  
if ((object is subView) && object.tag == selectViewTagValue){object.removeFromSuperview() }

Comment: My pleasure bro :)

Comment: Bro i have another issue come up... kindly check the below ans i have provided with image.....pls help me with this :p

Answer (score 1):

Try to change cancel action like this:

```
func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let myView = sender.superview {
        myView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Just remove the button's container view, not the global myView.

Comment: According to the storyboard, the sub view contains the button directly, this's the simplest way to remove the view itself. Why down voted it? I don't understand.

Comment: ya I also dont know who assign the downvote, your answer will work

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, yes, we cannot stop the over self-confident but stupid mind. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fixed the delete issue, but currently I am unable to relocate the positions the customs views, as shows in the picture below, Kindly help me with this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In this case the best approach is to use tableView in which load custom cell.   Then whenever you delete one cell remaining cells automatically relocate itself.